# Какой заголовочный файл из стандартной библиотеки Си отвечает за обработку нажатий клавиш, работа в консоли MacOS

Tags: c, macos, библиотека, ansi

Необходимо обработать нажатие клавиш в реальном времени в консоли MacOS.

Comment: <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h> , а лучше просто почитать их официальную документацию https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices

Comment: Никакой. В стандартной библиотеке С средства обработки клавиатурного ввода отсутствуют. Как максимум, вместо ввода можно читать экранирующие последовательности из стандартного ввода.